# Passing server argument in Eclipse and then reading it in application

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly

I have Wildfly server in Eclipse Mars. In *Open launch configuration*, in section *Program argumenst* I have added `Dmyarg.dir="Value"`.

Then, in application, I have code:

```
 RuntimeMXBean mxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();

 for(String arg : mxBean.getInputArguments()){
    if(arg.startsWith("Dmyarg.dir")){
        String [] filePath = arg.split("=");
        break;
    }
 }
```

After running my server from Eclipse, there is no argument passed.
Afrer running my server by myself, my application can find this argument.

How can I add argument in Eclipse that would be displayed there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [RuntimeMXBean#getInputArguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html#getInputArguments()) documentation it

> Returns the input arguments passed to the Java virtual machine which
>   does not include the arguments to the main method.

So if you want to see your argument in result of `getInputArguments` call you need to pass it to JVM. i.e. in Eclipse IDE you should type `-Dmyarg.dir="Value"` in "VM arguments" filed of launch configuration. And process it as

```
 RuntimeMXBean mxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();

 for(String arg : mxBean.getInputArguments()){
    if(arg.startsWith("-Dmyarg.dir")){
        String [] filePath = arg.split("=");
        break;
    }
 }
```

Also note that you can use next code to get value of VM argument passed as `-Dmyarg.dir="Value"`

```
System.getProperty("myarg.dir")
```

See [documentation for java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) command:

> **-Dproperty=value**
>   Sets a system property value.
>
> If value is a string that contains spaces, then you must enclose the
>   string in double quotation marks:
>
> java -Dmydir="some string" SomeClass